# UITableView, cellForRowAt problem in assigning data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

when I am trying to assign data into a label in tableview cell while reading data from firestore document field value, here is the problem when i scroll the tableview the data in the tableview cells are moving, which looks very ugly.

```
self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "OpenCell")
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "OpenCell") as! OpenCell
let rcell = self.r[indexPath.row]


db.collection("collectionString").document(rcell.value).getDocument() { (docSnapshot, err) in
                    if let err=err {
                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                    } else {

                        guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, (docSnapshot.exists) else {
                            return
                        }

                        let myData = docSnapshot.data()
                        let Name : String = myData!["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                        if Name == ""{
                            cell.name.text = "Name"
                        }
                        else{
                            cell.name.text = Name
                        }
               }
       }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not how you should fetch your dataSource. You should fetch all of the cell data before hand if possible, or at least a batch of it and keep it ready to feed the tableView in `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: use this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching for prefetching the data source before cell even apears